# When will GCC support C++11 regex_token_iterator?

Tags: g++

When will GCC support for C++11 `regex_token_iterator`? Some of regex seems to be implemented, but the token iterator is not supported yet in my 32-bit Ubuntu/Linaro (version `4.7.2-4precise1`) installation.

Any idea *when* this will be available?

Comment: Similar question on SO: [Compile std::regex_iterator with gcc](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8561850/1254292) And [online GNU GCC docs say: no](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.200x)

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing it's not even implemented in the development versions of GNU GCC as listed [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.tr1):

> This page describes the TR1 support in mainline GCC SVN, not in any particular release.
>
> [...]
>
> ```
> 7.12.2    Class template regex_token_iterator N    
> 7.12.2.1  regex_token_iterator constructors   N    
> 7.12.2.2  regex_token_iterator comparisons    N    
> 7.12.2.3  regex_token_iterator dereference    N    
> 7.12.2.4  regex_token_iterator increment      N
> ```

The C++ TR1 standard became part of the C++11 standard later [as Wikipedia explains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++_Technical_Report_1).

So, in my opinion, this is more of a question you should ask on the [mailing list of GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/lists.html). They may have a good reasons to have this feature a lower priority or to not have it implemented.